# Giving description to Name column Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, column

I have observed that while inside a document library we can provide descriptions to columns, which shows up under the input next to the specific field. But as 'Name' column is a system column in SharePoint 2013 online, how can i provide description to it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, waiting to hear from you about my answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Name` column is from **Document** content type. It is not editable from browser or designer.
[image]

See there is no link in the `Name` column. You will find the same thing in the SharePoint Designer also.

Interestingly, It is editable from custom code (***C#***, ***JavaScript*** and ***PowerShell***).

## JavaScript Example

```
function addOrUpdateDescriptionOfColumn(libraryName, columnName, description) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(libraryName);
    var fields = list.get_fields();
    var theField = fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(columnName);

    theField.set_description(description);
    theField.update();
    context.load(theField);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onError);


    function onSuccess() {
        alert("Description updated successfully");
    }

    function onError(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
}
```

**PS:** `FileLeafRef` is the in the internal name of the `Name` column.You can use your browser's console to add/update the description of a column.

1. Login your site where your list/library exists
2. Open developer tool (**Press F12**) and go to console
3. Paste above function and press **Enter**
4. The call `addOrUpdateDescriptionOfColumn()` function with parameters. For example, `addOrUpdateDescriptionOfColumn("MAST", "FileLeafRef", " Please follow the required naming convention.");`

## Result

After applying above code you should get following result.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Atish! Do i have to insert the above JavaScript code into a web part like script editor which will be added into my document library?  Also will I have to add any reference to my script editor like jquery? So that this function works.

Comment: No no. Just execute above function in your browser's console. That's it. Can you give your list/library name, column name and description so that I can write the full code for you.

Comment: library name :- MAST , column name :- Name , description :- Please follow the required naming convention.

Comment: And Atish i have one more question in this case will my client too executing this code in his/her browsers console every time, just to apply these changes?

Comment: No. You have to execute it only once.

Comment: Copy all code from here https://jsbin.com/jukiqitoto/edit?js and paste in console and then press enter. Finally check in the browser. Let me know what happens after applying these code.

Comment: It worked or not? @mohdtahir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43392/discussion-between-mohd-tahir-and-atish-dipongkor).

Comment: It works thank you so much, this is actually pretty amazing. You saved me a lot time.

Comment: Will this populate for everyone or just the user that implements it?