# Adding Custom Description to FileLeafRef(Name) BuiltInField Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I came across this post [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/188389/giving-description-to-name-column-document-library) and the OP said the solution had worked for them.

Solution from the above post:

```
function addOrUpdateDescriptionOfColumn(libraryName, columnName, description) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(libraryName);
    var fields = list.get_fields();
    var theField = fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(columnName);

    theField.set_description(description);
    theField.update();
    context.load(theField);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onError);


    function onSuccess() {
        alert("Description updated successfully");
    }

    function onError(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
}

addOrUpdateDescriptionOfColumn("Library Name", "FileLeafRef", " Please follow the required naming convention.");
```

According to the marked answer, all that needs to be done is to open developer tools, and copy & paste that script into the console.

I did that, and I get the alert saying "Description updated Sucessfully", and when I hard refresh the page, add a new document, the description does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can update the `FileLeafRef` field in SharePoint Online any longer.

I tried updating `FileLeafRef` using JavaScript, PowerShell and via  UI. And none of the updates seem to affect this field at all.

You can verify it by doing the following:

- Navigate to the Library settings.
- Click on any field. For example, `Title`. You'll see the field's details page.
- In the browser's address bar, at the end of the URL, right after `&Field=`, replace the field name from `Title` to `FileLeafRef`:

[image]

- Click OK to apply changes

As a result nothing will happen. You can successfully try this "trick" with any other field but it won't work with `FileLeafRef`.

Interestingly, `FileLeafRef` is not **Sealed** and not **ReadOnlyField**. So that's not an issue. Also, **DenyAddAndCustomizePages** has nothing to do with an ability to update the `FileLeafRef`field.